# Python ftputil outputting to terminal although I want to redirect output to a file

Tags: python-3.x, logging, ftputil

I'm running a Python3 script on the terminal, and on my terminal it writes out a lot of `print()` statements that I added, as well as output from libraries I'm using.

I wish to save the output in a file, so I run the script like this.

`python3 myscript.py > logfile.txt`

Everything I `print()` from within Python now goes into the file as I want, instead of being printed to my terminal.

However, within this script I'm also using the [ftputil](https://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac) library to download files, and some output from ftputil still shows on the terminal where I ran the script. So now the output of my program is split in 2 parts, which makes it less useful.

```
download-ftp.py:160: DeprecationWarning: `use_list_a_option` will default to `False` in ftputil 4.x.x with ftputil.FTPHost(ftp_addr, ftp_user, ftp_pw) as ftp_host:
```

What is needed to make the output from ftputil also go into the file that I want?

Comment: Take a look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that one and based on the top answer, I did as suggested ```A far more common method is to use shell redirection when executing (same on Windows and Linux):

$ python foo.py > file```  . Might need to read the rest though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why the `ftputil` output is not redirected but if it is pure python, changing the sys.stdout and sys.stderr should work...

Comment: I think I might need to redirect stderr as well, as explained here https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file

Comment: ftputil maintainer here. :-) Normally there shouldn't be any shell output from ftputil. What's the output you're seeing that might come from ftputil?

Comment: @sschwarzer ```download-ftp.py:160: DeprecationWarning: `use_list_a_option` will default to `False` in ftputil 4.x.x
  with ftputil.FTPHost(ftp_addr, ftp_user, ftp_pw) as ftp_host:```     The rest of the output was actually from something else, I noticed. But this warning came from ftputil as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this deprecation warning is from ftputil.

ftputil uses the Python [`warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) to show this warning. The `warnings` module not only outputs warnings (by default to stderr), but also offers ways to control which warnings are actually shown (see [The Warnings Filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) and [Temporarily Suppressing Warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings)).

You can suppress the ftputil warning with

```py
import warnings

import ftputil


with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
    ftp_host = ftputil.FTPHost(host, user, password)
...
```

If you really *want* the deprecation warning in your log file, you can use the methods that others have suggested in the comments. Here's an example:

```py
import sys

import ftputil           


old_stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
try:
    ftp_host = ftputil.FTPHost(host, user, password)
finally:
    sys.stderr = old_stderr
```